# Mask RCNN huge jump of loss when training with multiple stages

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I train the model in a sequence from head layer to full layers, there is a huge jump of loss at the transition from heads to more layers.

However, if I train head first and then start a completely new training for more layers, there is no significant change of loss.

For example:

```
# Training - Stage 1
  epoch_count += 50
  print("Training network heads")
  model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE*100,
        epochs=epoch_count,
        layers='heads',
        augmentation=None)
# Training - Stage 2

  epoch_count += 100
  print("Fine tune Resnet stage 3 and up")
  model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE*50,
        epochs=epoch_count,
        layers='3+',
        augmentation=augmentation)
 # Training - Stage 3
  epoch_count += 150
  print("Fine tune all layers")
  model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE*10,
        epochs=epoch_count,
        layers='all',augmentation=augmentation)
```

Or:
I train the head layer first

```
# Training - Stage 1
  epoch_count += 50
  print("Training network heads")
  model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE*100,
        epochs=epoch_count,
        layers='heads',
  augmentation=None)
```

Finish and then start a new training with the same config continuing on the last weights: There is only a small jump of loss from the previous weight.

```
# Training - Stage 2

  epoch_count += 100
  print("Fine tune Resnet stage 3 and up")
  model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE*50,
        epochs=epoch_count,
        layers='3+',
        augmentation=augmentation)
```

[The grey line is the one with multiple stages in one def train(model) code and the blue line is the manual start of a new training of the second stage. (The blue line was not finished just to use as an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3AMS.png)

What could be the issue?

Comment: probably a stepsize that is too big, and only some iterations due to the decay falls back to a nice stepsize

Comment: What makes the difference if the algorithm continues training into the next stage by itself or if I start a new one with the next stage? It must initialize some parameters which reduce the jump.   Do you think it reinitializes the stepsize?